# How do I resolve this Entity Framework validation exception?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm receiving a validation exception that occurs only when my web app is running, but not when running automated tests using MSTest (even those tests use the same components).

The relevant code follows:

```
public abstract class BaseThing
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  //other properties
}

public class BaseThingConfig :EntityTypeConfiguration<BaseThing>
{
  ToTable("BaseThingTable");
  HasKey(d=>d.Id);
  Property(d=>d.Id).HasColumnName("SomeId");

  Map<ThingChild1>(d=>d.Requires("ThingType").HasValue(1);
  Map<ThingChild2>(d=>d.Requires("ThingType").HasValue(2);
  Map<ThingChild3>(d=>d.Requires("ThingType").HasValue(3);
}

public class ThingChild1 : BaseThing
{
  public long AggregateRootId {get;set;}
  //other stuff
}

    public class ThingChild1Config : EntityTypeConfiguration<ThingChild1>
    {         
Property(d=>d.AggregateRootId).IsRequired().HasColummName("DifferentId");
    }

//the other two child classes of BaseThing and their configs look similar

public class AggregateRoot
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<ThingChild1> ThingChildren1 {get; private set;}
  public virtual ICollection<ThingChild2> ThingChildren2 {get; private set;}
  public virtual ICollection<ThingChild2> ThingChildren3 {get; private set;}
}

public class AggregateRootConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<AggregateRoot>
{
  HasMany(d=>d.ThingChildren1).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(a=>a.AggregateRootId);
  HasMany(d=>d.ThingChildren2).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(a=>a.AggregateRootId);
  HasMany(d=>d.ThingChildren3).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(a=>a.AggregateRootId);
}
```

When I run code that uses these classes to return an instance of AggregateRoot from the database using its ID, everything runs fine. But when I run the same code through our web app (which uses SimpleInjector to get the DbContext into play), I get the following exception as I step over the call to `dbContext.AggregateRoots.FirstOrDefault(d=>d.Id=id);`

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> DifferentId: : There is no property with name 'DifferentId'
>   defined in the type referred to by Role 'BaseThing'.  DifferentId:
>   : There is no property with name 'DifferentId' defined in the type
>   referred to by Role 'BaseThing'.

I've attempted moving that property up to the base class, removing it from the child classes, and updating the child classes, but that causes other things to go south, like FK violations. I followed that trail for a while, but couldn't make anything work.

We're using EF 6.2.

If any one has any ideas, I'd love to hear them. Hopefully my code sample makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the simple injector tag is only here because it is used in your AppDomain. I don't see any relation between simple injector and your problem.

Comment: @Ric Removed it.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, incuding the stack traces of any inner exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, and am kind of embarrassed by the solution. Turns out the two projects in our solution that reference the entity framework were not referencing the same version. One, that which containers our IoC bootstrapping, referenced 6.0 and the other, which contained the actual EF-related classes (DbContexts, EntityConfigurations), referenced 6.2. Both read "6.0.0.0" in the references properties, so it got overlooked. Once I updated the former project to 6.2 the problem went away.